# Selecting a sub-range in a Named Table with vba in excel

Tags: datatable, range

Is there an easy way of selecting a sub-range in a Name Table, i.e. a list object.  For example I have a Named Table TABLE1 as shown below.  I would like to copy a sub-range of cells and paste them into another portion of the table.  I would prefer  to do this without having to use a loop.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lxQX.jpg)

I want to copy the 2 cells circled in red and paste them into the cells circled in green. The red cells are listrow 11 and listcolumn 2 & 3 of Table1.  The target cells are listrow 12 and listcolumn 2 & 3 of Table1.  I want to select the range of the 2 cells and paste them into a range of the target cells.  I dont't seem to see how to create a sub-range.  I know of ranges using Listrows or Listcolumn or Databodyrange but these refer to the full cells in the respective column or row.  I don't want to use the underlying worksheet cell address, ie. D14:E14.

Thanking anyone in advance for their help.

As you can see below, as a work around I copy and paste the cells independently.  Since there are only 2 cells this is not over burdening.  However if there were more cells it would make more difficult.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EndTy.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]